# Change Default Branch while creating new pull request

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When i create a new pull request in VSTS, default branch is selected as Master. Is there a way to change this configuration and set our own branch?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the repo's default branch. This can be done on the repository settings page -- the same place you'd configure branch policies or repo security. You can right click on any branch and choose it as the default.